# WPF Refactoring: Moving DataTemplate to another file

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I've got some dozen of report which can be viewed by the same WPF form.

This is achieved by using many DataTemplate but this leads to a file long 2500 rows.

Is it possible to move the definition of the DataTemplate to another file?

Which kind of solution could help in this objective?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resource Dictionaries are great to separate XAML [Using a Resource Dictionary in WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35346/Using-a-Resource-Dictionary-in-WPF)